# Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?

Tags: html, audio

I haven't found any resources on how to do that. Something as simple as changing the color of the player would be nice to have :)

Comment: Different browsers react differently to styling of the audio element - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765938/325251

Comment: yes, and on ie it looks the worst. how can they make it look so bad?

Comment: video styling cross browser answer http://advprog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/styling-html-media-inner-workings.html

Comment: @Mousey Unfortunately that's not cross-browser at all. It's only Webkit and maybe Opera.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes! The HTML5 audio tag with the "controls" attribute uses the browser's default player. You can customize it to your liking by not using the browser controls, but rolling your own controls and talking to the audio API via javascript.

Luckily, other people have already done this.  My favorite player right now is [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), it is very stylable and works great.  Check it out.

Comment: So the answer is "no, it is not possible, you must use an external player"?

Comment: @Fernando: it is indeed possible. This answers the question "is it possible?"

Comment: Thank you @dsschnau. I posted my comment because the question is about styling html5 _video_ tag, and all the answers are more or less like _yes, it is possible, using other tags_.

Comment: jplayer is not easily customizable if you don't want to use one of its skins out of the box. I'd like a player that is bare bones -- tiny and easily skinnable.

Comment: So, is that really a "no"? Rolling your own UI is not the same thing a stying existing markup.

Comment: This answer is really just a link to a resource. What if jPlayer _goes away_?

Comment: This answer should be corrected. Also the project jplayer on github is not updated since 2017.

Comment: The question asks can you style the audio tag. Your answer is "yes, just hide it and build your own controls". See the problem here?

Answer (score 130):

Yes: you can hide the built-in browser UI (by removing the `controls` attribute from `audio`) and instead build your own interface and control the playback using Javascript ([source](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-audio.php#gist26771285)):

```
<audio id="player" src="vincent.mp3"></audio>
<div> 
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button> 
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1">Vol +</button> 
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1">Vol -</button> 
</div>
```

You can then style the elements however you wish using CSS.

MDN [HTMLAudioElement API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)

Comment: surely this (the .play) wouldn't work on IOS as it is blocked (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776548/why-cant-javascript-play-audio-files-on-iphone-safari)

Comment: @user1432181 your response seems incorrect. The question you linked to says that iOS blocks autoplay and requires the playing to be initiated by a user interaction. The code provided in this answer runs after a click event.

Comment: Complete but simple answer that actually answers the question and doesn't refer to 3rd party bs (goes to dependancy & responsibility), that also happens to make me hit my head for not seeing this in the first place  Me like.

Answer (score 126):

```
<audio>

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel

audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container

audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display

audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display

audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider

audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button
```

REFERENCE: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/72fef91ac1ef679207f51def8133b336a6f6588f/Source/core/css/mediaControls.css?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F

Comment: Poor presentation but usefull CSS selector !

Comment: can you please show an exemple how to use these ? just sample code ?

Comment: This is only supported by webkit-based browsers (e.g not Firefox, IE, etc.)

Comment: Very nice hacking , it's correct answer and many thanks ! i change style of audio tag without pain and additional JS code , ViVa Fabio

Comment: And for Safari?

Comment: Appears to be copy/pasted from https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

Comment: let's collaborate! Your answer does not help the community.

Comment: Note that some things like the buttons are background-images in those pseudo-elements. So it seems might have to completely replace the background-image to get even different colors.

Answer (score 45):

some color tunings

```
audio {
    filter: sepia(20%) saturate(70%) grayscale(1) contrast(99%) invert(12%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: this is a quick and dirty way to change the basic colors of the player, very handy

Comment: I dusted off my login credentials to sign in, upvote this, and say "THANK YOU".

Answer (score 32):

The appearance of the tag is browser-dependent, but you can hide it, build your own interface and control the playback using Javascript.

Answer (score 9):

Ken had it right as well.

a `css` tag:

```
audio {

}
```

will get you some results.  seems it doesnt want the player any height above or below 25px but the width can be shortened or lengthened to an extent.

this was good enough for me; see this example (warning, audio plays automatically): [www.thenewyorkerdeliinc.com](http://www.thenewyorkerdeliinc.com)

Comment: For me, a big issue is Internet Explorer. It looks terrible and different color and much bigger size than the other browser players, even though the width is set to 150px

Comment: If you need to get IE9+ player into a small space, a height of 25px and width of 100px worked for me. I think the height of 25px was key, but larger numbers didn't work for whatever reason.

Comment: The link is down unfortunately

Answer (score 8):

Missing the most important one IMO the container for the controls `::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure`:

```
&::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Chrome, turned on **"Show user agent shadow DOM"** in Chrome Dev Tool settings

[image: Show user agent shadow DOM]

Now you'll able to see all the pseudos

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel

audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button

audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button

...
```

[image]

and now you can style them

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To change just the colour of the player, simply address the audio tag in your css file, for instance on one of my sites the player became invisible (white on white) so I added:

```
audio {
    background-color: #95B9C7;
}
```

This changed the player to light blue.

Comment: This does not change the color of my player, it only puts a background color behind it. Any idea why?

Comment: @Tom because this solution is not for changing the default gray background of the player :-) Same result as you for me.

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome and on Firefox it seems to put the color over the original color, so you get a mixed color and if you try to use a light color you won't see any change.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible, from @Fábio Zangirolami answer

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel, video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
                background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some customizations on the Audio component. Here is what i did.

```
audio {
/*border-radius: 90px;*/
width: 250px;
height: 45px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
display: none !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
display: none !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-container.closed {
display: none !important;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-container{
display: none !important;
}
```

I found that these customizations only works for Edge and Chrome. Not Firefox..

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTMLMediaElement Api to create your own [audioplayer with html/css](https://www.brainbeast.best/customizable-audio-player-for-webpages/). It is likely the only option. Because the default player can't be styled.

Answer (score -7):

If you want to style the browsers standard music player in the CSS:

```
audio {
    enter code here;
}
```

Comment: not complete description is very simple and i can use this way for styling all element audio

Comment: Even a cursory check of this answer would have revealed that it's wrong.