# Audio Control UI customization in HTML

Tags: html, audio-player

Is there any method to modify Audio Control's UI in HTML file? I want to make the control's button bigger for mobile browser. 
I am playing with the following tutorial code:

```
<audio controls="controls">   
<source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>   
<source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
Your browser does not support this audio 
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Basically you can't style the existing look, but you can create your own UI and use the Javascript API.