# remove background subtitle in chrome with html5 video

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video-subtitles

My project is to create a video streaming app using **NextJS**, where I want to display a video and also its subtitles.

**Problem:**
In Chrome browser the subtitles have a background and I want to remove it (or change its height):

[image]

In Firefox or Safari it all works fine.

**My code**:

```
margin: auto;   
outline-offset: 0.5px;  
outline: 100vw solid
rgba(32, 35, 37, 0.85);   
background-image: linear-gradient(
                                    to bottom,
                                    rgba(32, 35, 37, 0.85),
                                    rgba(32, 35, 37, 0.85)   
                                );
```

I also tried `background-color` but it is not working.

Is there any solution?

Comment: **PS:** Read [this MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video#styling_the_displayed_subtitles) and also see if [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48633014/2057709) helps you. Basically you have to use `::cue` to access the text for styling.

Comment: thanks.i use it but not working again....i want to  change height