# Can I style this audio player?

Tags: html, css, media-player

I am trying to make a very simple audio player, and I have come across this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yJfbX/2/  It is what I really need, but the question is can I really STYLE it?

Here is the code:

```
JS: var audio    = new Audio();
    playlist = $('#playlist');

               playlist.on('click', 'li', function() {
                  playlist.find('.current').removeClass('current');
                  $(this).addClass('current');
                  audio.src = $(this).data('src');
                  audio.play();
               }).find('li:first').trigger('click');

audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="playlist">
    <li data-src="http://dp0169.free.fr/Musique/Air/Air%20-%20Talkie%20Walkie/02%20Cherry%20Blossom%20Girl.mp3">Cherry Blossom Girl (AIR)</li>
    <li data-src="http://dp0169.free.fr/Musique/Air/Air%20-%20Talkie%20Walkie/04%20Universal%20Traveller.mp3">Universal Traveller (AIR)</li>
    <li data-src="">Another Day (AIR(</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag

Comment: I have came across that post as well, It was not clear for me, as I don't really know where to find the API, is it an easy task?

Comment: If you never work before with Audio/Video this will be little bit difficult for you anyway try this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: The solution presented in the link I shared is to create your own custom player (style-wise) that uses javascript to interact with the existing audio player and simply hide the existing audio player. I hope that makes sense. I will try to create a simple example.

Comment: What I am after is very very basic audio player, i.e. a Play / Pause Button + Progress Bar and the Value slider. That is all, I wanted to style them the way I want as well, using CSS if possible. Please can someone help me but getting me started? I have bought few from online sites, but all didn't work! they are far too complex and just a nightmare to edit. any help will be much appreciated

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nEQXd/ An incredibly simplistic example to get you heading in the right direction. With some knowledge of javascript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML, you can create your own player. Though, based on what seems to be your knowledge level, jplayer is probably your best bet.

Comment: @JoelWorsham Thank you very much that is what I was looking for! only few questions regarding this Fiddle please. 

How can I toggle the play? so it first appears with the pause icon, and when you click the icon changes to play and the music plays, and when you click again the music pauses and the pusses icon appears?

Comment: Through use of absolute positioning and changing the display between inline and none, this effect is achieved. http://jsfiddle.net/nEQXd/3/

Comment: @JoelWorsham Thank you, one last thing please, you don't have to do it, just direct me at-least, how can I add a very basic progress bar, or a counter instead? i.e. 2/3.0min

Comment: I know this isn't a super helpful thing to say, but I must suggest that you learn a bit more about javascript and jQuery, and perhaps CSS as well. Very good skills to have. Building a bar like that would require both research and time on my part because I never have before, so unfortunately I don't think I can help you farther. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably better using something like jPlayer for which you can create your own skins and styles. I've used it on many projects and it's never let me down API wise.

http://jplayer.org/