# add cursor: pointer to audio element

Tags: javascript, html, css

got a quick one: how do I add a cursor style to my `<audio>` controls? When I add them via css the cursor only displays around the controls and not on the controls themselves.

Here's some code:

```
<audio class="_audio" src="http://www.somewebsite.co/assets/AudioSample-JOBS.mp3" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Of note: the element is created onclick via javascript, but that shouldn't come into play...

Comment: Try: `._audio:hover { cursor:pointer; }`

Comment: @DanielLisik yeah, that seems to work for Firefox, but not Chrome for some reason...

Comment: The style `cursor` is most definitely supported in Chrome. There must be some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but you can't style html media controls. 
What you can do is to make your own controls. If you're interested here's a good link: 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers react differently to styling of the audio element.

I tested [this sample](http://jsbin.com/cocixa/) in Chrome 39 & IE 11 on Windows 8.1.

```
audio { 
  width:45px; 
  height:25px;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

The cursor property works well in IE 11 but in Chrome the pointer shows up only on the left side of the audio button with the above styling