# Change the control colors in the HTML5 audio tag

Tags: css, html, firefox, html5-audio

Is it possible to change the 'play', 'pause', and 'volume' colors in the HTML5 audio tag.

They have a very dark color when using Firefox and they make the player look disabled.

Comment: I think these are **Shadow DOM** elements so it depends - http://caniuse.com/#search=shadow%20DOM - This article is on video but might relate. - http://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer: No. Currently, you cannot change the color of the controls of the HTML5 audio tag. If you enable the controls attribute, the appearance of the 'play', 'pause', and 'volume' will be dependent on the browser.

With more work though, you can use JavaScript to create your own audio player interface that connects to the audio element's API.

Your question is a more focused version of what was asked here:

[Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

And here are some articles on how to create a unique audio player:

http://serversideup.net/style-the-html-5-audio-element/

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081

Comment: It IS possible to style at least part of the controls through CSS. See: https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

Comment: There must be a way, i have not got too much into it but at least you can make the button white by using a filter

audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
     filter: invert(100%);
}