# Style the audio html tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add css styles to the audio tag? I have tried but I couldn't.

Thanks.

```html
<li class="music">
    <div class="podcast">
        <div class="img-episodes-container">
            <img  src="images/podcast1.jpg" alt="microfono">
        </div>

        <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>

        <audio controls>
            <source src="sounds/sound1.mp3">
        </audio>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: You can't but you can make your own player and then style it any way you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367263/change-the-control-colors-in-the-html5-audio-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Answer (score 7):

This is possible!

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
 <li class="music">
   <div class="podcast">
     <div class="img-episodes-container">
       <img src="images/podcast1.jpg" alt="microfono">
     </div>
     <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
     <audio controls>
       <source src="sounds/sound1.mp3">
     </audio>
   </div>
 </li>
```

Here is the full list:

> audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button
>
> audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button

As per this incomplete answer: [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33948255/11700321)

**Please note** these are the Chrome / Webkit supported tags. There may or may not be Firefox / IE11 supported tags for the `audio` element as there is little-to-no documentation on `-moz` or `-ms` prefixing conventions/support for this tag.

Comment: But not possible for non-webkit browsers.

Comment: As per my final comments in my answer, there is little-to-no documentation on `-moz` or `-ms` prefixing conventions/support for the `audio` tag, so it is unclear if there is support in Firefox / IE. :)

Comment: Yep Firefox doesn't support styling the player with CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio (see "Styling with CSS").

Comment: I would argue with enough persistance, nearly anything is possible: `@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  audio {
    background-color: red;
     transform: scale(1.7);
     margin-left: 100px;
  }
}` Some really basic/hacky styling is possible with browser-specific tags

Comment: This is not a complete list, its just the same one everyone copy/pastes. Heres a couple more, but I'm sure there's many more.
`::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure`
`::-internal-media-controls-cast-button`

Answer (score 0):

You can Style the audio Tag as the answer above mentioned, but the issue is it will not have support on most of the browsers which might cause your application for not having cross browser compatibility, I suggest you to design a custom player and make functionality like the audio tag , it will more feasible for you.