# How to style the playback rate menu of an audio html tag?

Tags: html, css, audio, styles, media

I want to style / hide this menu icon here:

[image]

I already looked into https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/main/Source/core/css/mediaControls.css
but I can not find any reference to it.

Comment: Make a custom `<audio>` element using React or something, that has similar display to the original `<audio controls>`, but that does not have the three dots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style the audio html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024693/style-the-audio-html-tag)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag/

Comment: @SuperStormer No, both do not cover my issue with styling the audio tag.

Comment: @Plantt Yes, that could be an alternative solution for my issue. But I wonder why I can't find a way to style this context menu icon - but everything else seems to be style-able.

Comment: @AndréFiedler Maybe something with `-webkit-appearance`?