# Why can't JavaScript .play() audio files on iPhone safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, audio, safari

I've got a JavaScript web app working that plays some audio periodically like this:

```
var SOUND_SUCCESS = new Audio('success.mp3');
SOUND_SUCCESS.play();
```

This works great on desktop browsers (tested in Edge and Chrome), but it doesn't play on Safari on iPhone.

I've looked around Stack Overflow, and I found some answers from a couple of years ago that it's not possible to play audio from Safari unless you're in that full screen player. Is this still the case?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but the repetition of the sounds does not work with my code.
I opened a question here if anyone can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716844/audio-on-ios-does-not-work-properly-it-only-works-the-first-time

Answer (score 54, accepted):

iOS disables autoplay, instead requiring that play be initiated as part of a user interaction (e.g., you can start playback within a touchstart listener). There's a bit of documentation about this on [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html). There's also this article [Overcoming iOS HTML5 audio limitations](https://web.archive.org/web/20170215083556/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/) on IBM's developer site that has examples and more detail.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but the repetition of the sounds does not work with my code.
I opened a question here if anyone can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716844/audio-on-ios-does-not-work-properly-it-only-works-the-first-time

Answer (score 63):

To add to xingliang cai's response, here's a code sample I got to work for me (edited below to work on iOS14, thanks @AndrewL!):

```
const soundEffect = new Audio();
soundEffect.autoplay = true;

// onClick of first interaction on page before I need the sounds
// (This is a tiny MP3 file that is silent and extremely short - retrieved from https://bigsoundbank.com and then modified)
soundEffect.src = "data:audio/mpeg;base64,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";

// later on when you actually want to play a sound at any point without user interaction
soundEffect.src = 'path/to/file.mp3';
```

Comment: Excellent.  Works well in Angular too.

Comment: I've searched for so long and everywhere I looked it said it wasn't possible to do something like this. Thank you

Comment: This does not work anymore for me on Safari Version 14.0.3 :/ Returns the classic `Unhandled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted.`

Comment: I bet it would work if you wrapped the initial play call in a 1 second timeout. @capitalg

Comment: This is really weird. After changing the src (http://www.xxx.xxx/test.mp3). It plays the sound but my safari webinspector on the iPad throws the error "Unhandled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted." as @capitalg mentioned. Its play but I just want to make it perfect. So any idea how to solve the error ?

Comment: My problem was that I wanted to playback something I recorded via the browser but apple has not implemented the playback of browser recorded material - but the error shown is the same - see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85851 and https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/issues/655

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer no longer works for iOS 14.

Comment: For iOS 14, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107904/148142

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer to your solution, @AndrewL!

Comment: An even shorter version is `soundEffect.src = "data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRigAAABXQVZFZm10IBIAAAABAAEARKwAAIhYAQACABAAAABkYXRhAgAAAAEA";`. From here - https://gist.github.com/novwhisky/8a1a0168b94f3b6abfaa

Comment: Thank you! Works with Safari on iOS 15.7.6.

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari 17.3 even with a timeout for the second (real source) play.
Unhandled Promise Rejection

Comment: auto play and mute is no necessary. Key is, just using the same audio element

Answer (score 26):

IOS on mobile disable automatic sound playing by default. So to get around this problem. You could put enable/disable switch button somewhere on the page and  play some sound using an audio element("**audioElement**") if the user click the button switch.

After that, the same "**audioElement**" can be used to play future sounds by changing its "**src**" attribute and call its "**play()**" method, without any further user interaction.

Comment: I found the second part of this answer useful - you can change `Audio(x).src` and call `play()` but you cannot make a new Audio object and the call `play()` without user interaction.

Comment: Stunning. Thanks a lot for investigating and solving this! Creating a `new Audio()` on a user interaction and storing that, and then later changing that object's `.src` and calling `.play()` on it worked (using React and useRef in my case). Cheers

Answer (score 14):

To get @user2415116's solution to work in iOS 14, I did this:

```
const soundEffect = new Audio();
soundEffect.autoplay = true;

// onClick of first interaction on page before I need the sounds
// (This is a tiny MP3 file that is silent and extremely short - retrieved from https://bigsoundbank.com and then modified)
soundEffect.src = "data:audio/mpeg;base64,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";

// later on when you actually want to play a sound at any point without user interaction
soundEffect.src = 'path/to/file.mp3';
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been answered, but for some this may help. If you have the .play trigger in a setTimeout function you must keep the time below 951.

`setTimeout(function(){$('audio').play}, 999)` prevents auto play

`setTimeout(function(){$('audio').play}, 950)` auto play works

Comment: Why less than 951ms?

Comment: It's just a safer value. 975 might work, but I didn't test it. I know 999 prevents the video/audio from auto playing.I didn't feel like testing all the numbers between 950-999 to find the boundary. lol.

Comment: This looks silly but I had the same experience. When I setup a event listener (eg. button click / tap) and fire the audio within +/- 950 ms it works just fine. Whenever the delay is above 996 ms the audio is blocked with an error message like: 
>NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly becouse the user denied permission.

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
    document.getElementById('audio').muted = false
    document.getElementById('audio').play()
  })
})
```

As soon as the user scrolls, the sound plays

Comment: you should ideally remove the event listeners on the return callback of the useEffect as well.

Answer (score 2):

Safari gives priority to the soundtrack of videos over audio files! If a video has a soundtrack, even if it is silent and set to mute it will block the audio. The solution is to strip the soundtrack from the video, not record over it.
I hope this helps some one! I lost days of work with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question but something that might help some people out, in my case (ofcourse this might not be viable in all cases), it helped to play all audio files for 1millisecond, then pause them. After that, if you resume playing the audio it works without issue.

```
   playButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      introVid.play();
      audioPlayers[0].play(); //every array element is constructed using new Audio("yourlink");
      audioPlayers[1].play();
      audioPlayers[2].play();
      audioPlayers[3].play();
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        audioPlayers[0].pause();
        audioPlayers[1].pause();
        audioPlayers[2].pause();
        audioPlayers[3].pause();
      },1);
    })
```

Comment: This is working solution so far

Answer (score 0):

In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), preload and autoplay are disabled, unless the user is on a cellular network and be charged per data unit. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
I have simplified a working code for my project where I need to play button click sound, hope this will help.

```
 <button class="js-button-clicked">Button 1</button>
 <button class="js-button-clicked" >Button 2</button>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
  // Check if the browser supports web audio. Safari wants a prefix.
  if ("AudioContext" in window || "webkitAudioContext" in window) {
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here's the part for just playing an audio file.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var ButtonPlay = function ButtonPlay(audioBuffer) {
      var source = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = audioBuffer;
      source.connect(context.destination);
      source.start();
    };

    var soundUrl = "https://images.skidos.com/video-js/button_pressed.mp3";
    var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var context = new AudioContext(); // Make it crossbrowser
    var gainNode = context.createGain();
    gainNode.gain.value = 1; // set volume to 100%
    var eventButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".js-button-clicked");
    var yodelBuffer = void 0;

    // The Promise-based syntax for BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData() is not supported in Safari(Webkit).
    window
      .fetch(soundUrl)
      .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then((arrayBuffer) =>
        context.decodeAudioData(
          arrayBuffer,
          (audioBuffer) => {
            yodelBuffer = audioBuffer;
          },
          (error) => console.error(error)
        )
      );
    eventButtons.forEach((el) =>
      el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        return ButtonPlay(yodelBuffer);
      })
    );
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here's the part for unlocking the audio context, probably for iOS only
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function unlock() {
      console.log("unlocking");
      // create empty buffer and play it
      var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, 1, 22050);
      var source = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;
      source.connect(context.destination);

      // play the file. noteOn is the older version of start()
      source.start ? source.start(0) : source.noteOn(0);

      // by checking the play state after some time, we know if we're really unlocked
    }
    // Try to unlock, so the unmute is hidden when not necessary (in most browsers).
    unlock();
  }
})();
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/himstar/pen/MWBeLvG

- tested on iPhoneXR, iPadAir and MacOS 12.5

Answer (score -4):

Haha, I outsmarted it like this.

Put in the page the **audio tag with autoplay (true)**

```
<audio id="beep" src={Assets.SOUND_BEEP} autoPlay />
```

It will play the sound once the element is mounted. *(Even on safari iOS)*

Then it seems you can play it whenever you want again by calling

```
document.getElementById('beep').play();
```

But now you may say, but I don't want to play the sound as autoplay.

Yes, I outsmarted it to put the **"muted"** property on that, and then set it to false when playing.

```
<audio id="beep" src={Assets.SOUND_BEEP} autoPlay muted />
```

And play:

```
document.getElementById('beep').muted = false;
document.getElementById('beep').play();
```