# HTML 5 play audio file on click mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mobile, onclick

I am trying to get an audio file to play on click. The code I'm using works fine in a browser but doesn't seem to work on any mobile device. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <audio id="audio" src="http://ricklemon.co.uk/game/sound.ogg" autostart="false" ></audio>
    <a onclick="PlaySound()"><img src="http://ricklemon.co.uk/game/images/speaker.png" width="200px" /></a>
    <script>
    function PlaySound() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
          sound.play()
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need another sound extensions too (mp3/mpeg for example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't JavaScript .play() audio files on iPhone safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776548/why-cant-javascript-play-audio-files-on-iphone-safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that ogg audio files does not work on neither windows phone nor ios so you should add another file with a .mp3 extension for it to work