# react component audio play not working in safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have built a react component for text to speech functionality. when i get the text from the props, whenever user click the button, it will go to a third party api and get an audio to play. it works all fine in chrome and firefox, but not safari. I search around in internet but none of the solution works. the follow is my component.

```
function TextToSpeechButtons(props) {
      
    function handleClick(text, language) {
        const audioSrc = `http://api.voicerss.org/?key=${api}&hl=${language}&src=${text}&r=-5&v=Chen`
    
        console.log(audioSrc)
        new Audio(audioSrc).play();
        
    };
  
    return(
            <div className="buttonContainer">
                <ButtonGroup>
                     <Button variant="outline-dark" onClick= {() => handleClick(props.english, 'en-gb')}></Button>
                </ButtonGroup>     
            </div>
    );
     
}
```

Is there any ideas to fix the problem in Safari? (iphone and mac)? thanks a lot!

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago.. I think this link will be very helpful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776548/why-cant-javascript-play-audio-files-on-iphone-safari

Comment: @MauricePheyton i did look at this post. my trigger is from a button click, i don't know why it doesn't work. and i do try the sound.play() , sound.src = url , sound.play() however, also no luck with that. could you please tell me how did you solve your problem? thanks 

Comment: @justicepenny Did you ever get this to work? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @ggrant just make sure your audio format is on this list. i just make sure the audio format is mp3

https://support.pocketcasts.com/article/supported-file-types-audio-video-web-player/