# Audio on IOS browsers is not being played

Tags: javascript, html, express, html5-audio

I'm trying to play an audio on a website. The audio is a buffer that comes from express server. It works on Windows, but it doesn't work on IOS neither in Chrome nor Safari. Here's html:

```
<audio controls>
    <source [src]="url" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Here's the server endpoint that sends buffer:

```
router.get("/audio/:objectId", async (req, res) => {
    const { objectId } = req.params;

    const audio = await getAudio(objectId);

    res.contentType('audio/wav');
    res.send(audio.buffer);
});
```

The audio works on Windows. On IOS request to the endpoint is made, and the status is 200, meaning that the buffer was sent to the browser, but the audio won't play anyway. I've tried using `Howler` and `MediaElement`, nothing works.

**How do I play audio on IOS?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't JavaScript .play() audio files on iPhone safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776548/why-cant-javascript-play-audio-files-on-iphone-safari)

Comment: @LeandroBardelli, no, I don't use autoplay. The answer says that user has to interact with the website before the sound can play, on my website I use default `<audio>` to play the audio, so user plays the audio whenever he wants. But the audio won't play even after user interaction