# Infinite loop in NextJS and React when setting Audio source after Audio.onended

Tags: reactjs, audio, next.js, react-hooks

iOS Safari has restrictions on playing audio that require user interaction before audio can be played. I'm trying to work around that at the moment [by altering the source of my initial Audio object rather than creating new Audio objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107904/148142), but running into an infinite loop.

My code works like this: I initialze my Audio in useEffect at the start of the render. I press a microphone button that sets the Audio src to a "play sound and play the noise -- then, I begin listening to the user's voice using React Speech Recognition.

```
 const [sourceAudio, setSourceAudio] = useState(null);

 function startListen() {
    if (tipMessage) {
      SpeechRecognition.startListening({
        language: foundConversation.language,
      });
      setTipMessage(false);
      sourceAudio.src = "/start-record.mp3"
      sourceAudio.play();
    } else {
      SpeechRecognition.startListening({
        language: foundConversation.language,
      });
      sourceAudio.src = "/start-record.mp3"
      sourceAudio.play();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSourceAudio(new Audio("/start-record.mp3"));
  }, []);
```

I also have a Stop listen function that plays when the user presses the button again:

```
  function stopListen() {
    SpeechRecognition.stopListening();
    sourceAudio.src = "/stop-record.mp3"
    sourceAudio.play();
  }
```

When the user is done speaking, I sent the message off to OpenAI API to retrieve a response (no audio is altered here), and the OpenAI message is sent to Azure Text to Speech, which returns an audio blob URL. I set the origin Audio source to this blob URL and play it. Using "onended," I call `startListen()` again to capture the user's response.

```
  async function azureVoice(audioContentGen) {
    const response = await fetch("/api/tts", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        text: audioContentGen,
        language: foundConversation.language,
        authUserId: user.id
      }),
    });

    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    const bufferData = jsonResponse.data;

    const arrayBuffer = Uint8Array.from(bufferData).buffer;
    const audioBlob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "audio/*" });
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);


    sourceAudio.src = audioUrl
    sourceAudio.play();

    sourceAudio.onended = () => {
      startListen();
    };
  }
```

I am able to switch the Audio source back and forth by clicking the initial microphone button many times, and the sources set correctly and the right audio is played with no infinite loops. However, when `startListen()` is called at the end of `azureVoice()`, `startListen()` loops over and over again and plays the start-record.mp3 sound effect infinitely. If I press the microphone button again to trigger `stopListen()`, the audio source switches correctly to 'stop-record.mp3' and plays the noise, but immediately calls `startListen()` again and continues the infinite loop.

I'm stuck on solving this one. I'm sure it's some issue with state or useEffect, but I'm not sure how to solve this while retaining the iOS Safari workaround. Any help is extremely appreciated.