# How to set up an audio tag within a footer of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to put into the code this:

```
<audio controls="">
  <source src="music/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Audio element not supported by your browser. 
</audio>
```

But, I want to be in the footer, or at the bottom of the visible screen to the user.

How to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into using the CSS `position: fixed` property.

Set up a container, set it's position to fixed and dock it to the bottom of the page using `bottom: 0`

### HTML

```
<div id="audioContainer">
    <audio></audio>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#audioContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: @IvanKušaković looks good, with some practice things will come to you. If the answer is correct, then please accept it.

Comment: How to do that? I am new on this site. And why system tells me that me question is duplicated?

Comment: @IvanKušaković it's not - just listed as a _possible_ duplicate of another question (ie the same thing being asked). If you see the up and down arrow next to my answer, there should also be a check mark there that you can click

Comment: Nice :) I've checked it. Have a nice day!