# Are there any resources for react that can replace htlm5 audio tags?

Tags: audio, reactjs, npm, components

I am currently working on something of a soundcloud clone and for now I'm simply having all the audio files render as html5 audio tags. Are there any nice react equivalents I can npm install to make my audio a wave or appear dynamic? I'm very thankful for any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

In searching online for you, I see a few options available to you.

Here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-recorder (might not be as helpful, but worth noting)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/hymn

What exactly are you trying to achieve?  These libraries might be helpful depending on the exact details.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126871/1026017) shows how to use your own controls to stylize the player however you so desire.

Comment: Well the audio tag simply gives the play button and a scrubbing bar, I was hoping for something that would take audio as a source and render something that looks dynamic or better looking than the html5 audio element is underwhelming.

Comment: For looking better, can't you use CSS to style it how you want?

Comment: I dont think you can style the html audio element @Scott

Comment: You are right about using not being able to stylize it directly but why not use whatever controls you want and stylize those?  Then you get to choose the buttons and is better looking, even dynamic as you desire.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4126871/1026017