# Looking for a solution to load a url once then be able to click on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I need help with loading a URL one time into a HTML5 audio player and then be able to click on an elements to do additional controls.

This is the code so far:

```
<div class="primary">
 <article id="145">
  <div class="loaddata" data-rel="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3" onclick="setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('145').classList.add('dataloaded'); }, 1)"> Load "Song1" </div>
 </article>

 <article id="139">
  <div class="loaddata" data-rel="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/327164631-scott-johnson-27-tms-1281.mp3" onclick="setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('139').classList.add('dataloaded'); }, 1)"> Load "Song2" </div>
 </article>

 <article id="133" class="dataloaded">
  <div class="loaddata" data-rel="http://archive.org/download/DTH20170611/DTH20170611.mp3" onclick="setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('133').classList.add('dataloaded'); }, 1)"> Load "Song3" </div>
 </article>
```

The player:

```
<div class="audio-player-wrapper">
<div class="mejs__button mejs__group-left">
<div class="rewind-btn">
  <button title="Rewind 15 seconds">15</button>
</div>
<div class="playpause-btn">
  <button title="Play" class="play" id="ppbtn"></button>
</div>
<div class="forward-btn">
  <button title="Forward 15 seconds">15</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="current-time">00:00</div>
<div class="duration-time">00:00</div>
<div class="mejs__button mobile-mute">
<button class="mobile-mute-btn mobile-mute-off"></button>
</div>
<audio width="100%" height="75px" id="audio-player" controls="controls">
  <source id="sourceMp3" src="#" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".loaddata").on("click", function() {
var mp3Url = $(this).data('rel');
$("#audio-player_html5").attr('src', mp3Url);
});
$(".loaddata").click(function(){
$('.dataloaded').removeClass();
$('#ppbtn').click();
});
```

What the code above does is when a user clicks on `loaddata` the JS loads the url in `data-rel` into the `src` in `sourceMP3`. Then it scans 'primary' for any class called `dataloaded` and removes it. One millisecond later, it adds `dataloaded` to the article ID. Then the player starts playing the loaded URL in jquery `$('#ppbtn').click();`.

<del>What I'm trying to find is a way to load the URL on the first click then be able to control the play/pause button after the first click. I tried doing `.one()` on loading the URL once but when all three elements have been clicked once, it won't load the URL in the clicked element and all three elements `div.loaddata` can control the player.</del>

<del>I guess the easy way of explaining it: remove existing `.dataloaded`, add URL to player, add `.dataloaded` to the article that was clicked then be able to click on play/pause button only on the `div.loaddata` with 'dataloaded'.</del>

New question: is there a way to change a function when you click on an element? Like a new onclick?

Comment: Why have you got 3 separate click handlers on the same elements? Why don't you just write `$(".loaddata").click(function(){ var mp3Url = $(this).data('rel'); $("#audio-player_html5").attr('src', mp3Url); $('.dataloaded').removeClass(); $('#ppbtn').click(); $(this).addClass('.dataloaded'); });`?

Comment: what do you mean by "change a function"? you can either call another function or pass a different value as an argument (to an existing function).. the beauty of a function is that it can be re-used..

Comment: how do you call another function?

Comment: I guess another way I'm trying to find is to go from `<div onclick="first()" class "loaddata">` to `<div onclick="second()" class "loaddata">`

Comment: You change the value of a variable accessible to the function. Example: `var second = false; function firstOrSecond() { if (isSecond) { second(); } else { first(); } }; $('#someElement').click(firstOrSecond); $('#someOtherElement).click(function() { second = true; });` In this example, if you click `#someElement` then it calls `first`, unless `#someOtherElement` has been clicked at some point in the past, in which case it calls `second` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a working solution. It's not pretty but it works.

First I had two elements, one that loads the data and other controls the player.

```
<article id="145">
  <div class="loaddata" data-rel="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3" onclick="setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('145').classList.add('dataloaded');document.getElementById('145').classList.add('dataloaded'); }, 1);"> Load "Song1" </div>
  <div class="front-playpause">song loaded</div>
</article>
```

JS:

```
$(".loaddata").on("click", function() {
var mp3Url = $(this).data('rel');
$("#audio-player_html5").attr('src', mp3Url);
$('.dataloaded').removeClass();
$('#ppbtn').click();
});
$(".front-playpause").click(function(){
$('#ppbtn').click();
});
```

CSS:

```
.front-playpause {display:none}
.dataloaded .front-playpause {display:block}
.dataloaded .loaddata {display:none}
```

When `loaddata` is clicked, it adds the class 'dataloaded`to the article ID and then the CSS hides`loaddata`and then displays`front-playpause` and that's how I found a work around.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer this morning (but had a busy day!) .. I created a [jsfiddle  for playing multiple sounds](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qafxxftw/) some time ago but when I re-read the question this evening, it seemed not quite enough to cover what you were trying to do.

I found that there is a library called `MediaElement.js` available; the source code is outlined extensively in [this article](https://designshack.net/articles/css/custom-html5-audio-element-ui/) and there is a [demo](https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/html5-audio-player/index.html) also

Alternately there is very good (slightly lengthy!) article about designing a custom audio player by Rose (second name not given) [on her website](http://r.osey.me/code/audio/) where there is also a [demo](http://r.osey.me/code/audio/example/)

Best of all though, a fellow [SO-er](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2577852/michael-gaskill) gives [a wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37738603/1675954) to a similar question (about a year ago) and there is a [jsfiddle provided](https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/zo3ede1c/) in that answer (top pick i think..)

the code (hope there's room!):

```js
var audio_player = $("#audio-player");
var play_button = $('#play');
var progress_bar = $("#progressbar");
var time = $("#time");
var mute_button = $('#mute');
var volume_bar = $('#volume');
var more_info = $('#more-info-box');
var info_tray = $("#info-tray");
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var duration = 0;
var volume = 0.75;

player.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    duration = player.duration;
    progress_bar.progressbar("option", { 'max' : duration });
};

player.load();
player.volume = 0.75;
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    progress_bar.progressbar('value', player.currentTime);
    time.text(getTime(player.currentTime));
}, false);

function getTime(t) {
    var m=~~(t/60), s=~~(t % 60);
    return (m<10?"0"+m:m)+':'+(s<10?"0"+s:s);
}

function getProgressBarClickInfo(progress_bar, e) {
    var offset = progress_bar.position();
    var x = e.pageX - offset.left; // or e.offsetX (less support, though)
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top;  // or e.offsetY
    var max = progress_bar.progressbar("option", "max");
    var value = x * max / progress_bar.width();

    return { x: x, y: y, max: max, value: value };
}

volume_bar.progressbar({
    value : player.volume*100,
});

volume_bar.click(function(e) {
    var info = getProgressBarClickInfo($(this), e);
    volume_bar.progressbar('value', info.value);
    player.volume = info.value / info.max;
});

progress_bar.progressbar({
    value : player.currentTime,
});

progress_bar.click(function(e) {
    var info = getProgressBarClickInfo($(this), e);
    player.currentTime = player.duration / info.max * info.value;
});

play_button.click(function() {
    player[player.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-play", !player.paused);
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-pause", player.paused);
});

mute_button.click(function() {
    if (player.volume == 0) {
        player.volume = volume;
    } else {
        volume = player.volume;
        player.volume = 0;
    }

    volume_bar.progressbar('value', player.volume * 100);

    $(this).toggleClass("fa-volume-up", player.volume != 0);
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-volume-off", player.volume == 0);
});

more_info.click(function() {
    audio_player.animate({
        height: (audio_player.height() == 50) ? 100 : 50
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#audio-player {
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    color: white;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}

#controls {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 350px;
}

.time {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 14px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.ui-progressbar {
    background: #2B2B2B;
}

.ui-progressbar-value {
    background: white;
}

#progressbar, #volume {
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 16px;
}

#progressbar {
    width: 150px;
}

#play, #mute {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 17px;
}

#play {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#volume {
    width: 50px;
}

#more-info-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 350px;
    top: -50px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
}

#more-info-box, #more-info-box > span {
    cursor: context-menu;
}

#info-tray {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: -65px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<audio id="player">
    <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2543.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<div id="audio-player">
    <div id="controls">
        <i id="play" class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        <span id="start-time" class="time">00:00</span>
        <div id="progressbar"></div>
        <span id="time" class="time">00:00</span>
        <i id="mute" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        <div id="volume"></div>    
    </div>
    <div id="more-info-box">
        <span id="more-info">MORE INFO</span>
    </div>
    <div id="info-tray">
        Track: <span id="track">Semper Fidelis March</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope one of these solutions helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but these answers did not help me. I already have a player set up and these are for setting up a player.

Comment: @GregorySchultz i ran your current audio player in the snippet from 2 days ago.. it could be improved upon! Perhaps it would be wise to be open to suggestion..