# How can I style html audio player play button color?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I want to model my html audio tag for safari browser. I want to do the following things

1.change play button color
2.change time line slider thump color

I have the following code and it is almost ok in chrome but not in safari.

```
audio {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls,
  {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    direction: ltr;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure, {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel,  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    /* We use flex-start here to ensure that the play button is visible even
     * if we are too small to show all controls.
     *//*height: 25px;  
      background: #ffffff;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    bottom: auto;


    border-radius: 5px;
    /* The duration is also specified in MediaControlElements.cpp and LayoutTests/media/media-controls.js */
    /*transition: opacity 0.3s;
} */


/*audio:-webkit-full-page-media::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
video:-webkit-full-page-media::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    bottom: 0px;

}*/
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
    -webkit-appearance: media-mute-button;
    display: none;

}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-enclosure {
    display: none;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    -webkit-appearance: media-play-button;
    display: flex;
    flex: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:initial;
    color: blue;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container, video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container {
    -webkit-appearance: media-controls-background;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 1 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    height: 16px;
    min-width: 0;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display, video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display, video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
    -webkit-appearance: media-current-time-display;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    cursor: default;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 9px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #a7a9a9;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline, video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    -webkit-appearance: media-slider;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 8px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#1fa6e5;
    min-width: 25px;
    border: initial;
    color:initial;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider, video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
    -webkit-appearance: media-volume-slider;
    display: none;
    }
  audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  height: 25px;  
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)