# Why does the html5 <audio> tag display differently on chrome and IE?

Tags: css, html, mp3, embed

It looks clean and small in chrome and large and obnoxious in IE. See the two screenshots below.. Any ideas? Are there any mp3 hosting sites that have an embed option that looks something like the second option (chrome display)

[image] IE

[image] Chrome

EDIT:How can I make the IE one look more like the chrome version? Otherwise, is anyone aware of any hosting sites that have embed designs similar to the chrome version?

Comment: it is just default versions, but you can also use plugins for it or you can change design by yourself

Comment: For 'why' it would appear the IE developers were compelled to follow standards set for Metro Apps.  Is that the actual question or are you really asking how to change it?

Comment: @Affe, realistically I'm asking how to change it yes. Thanks for the insight though, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the `html5` audio/video controls with `css`, here's an example:

**HTML Markup**

```
<div id="video-controls" class="controls" data-state="hidden">
   <button id="playpause" type="button" data-state="play">Play/Pause</button>
   <button id="stop" type="button" data-state="stop">Stop</button>
   <div class="progress">
      <progress id="progress" value="0" min="0">
         <span id="progress-bar"></span>
      </progress>
   </div>
   <button id="mute" type="button" data-state="mute">Mute/Unmute</button>
   <button id="volinc" type="button" data-state="volup">Vol+</button>
   <button id="voldec" type="button" data-state="voldown">Vol-</button>
   <button id="fs" type="button" data-state="go-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>
</div>
```

**Basic styling**

The HTML video and its controls are all contained within a  element, which is given a maximum width and height (based on the dimensions of the video used) and centered within the page:

```
figure {
   max-width:64rem;
   width:100%;
   max-height:30.875rem;
   height:100%;
   margin:1.25rem auto;
   padding:1.051%;
   background-color:#666;
}
```

The video controls container itself also needs some styling so that it is set up the correct way:

```
.controls {
   width:100%;
   height:8.0971659919028340080971659919028%; /* of figure's height */
   position:relative;
}

audio {
    background-color: #95B9C7;
    /*etc...*/
}
```

---

SRC:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33948255/797495