# How to change the height of <audio> elements in Chrome? (Was able to do it fine in FF)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

So I developed a profile on a website of mine in Firefox (the website accepts HTML in profiles). I then opened it in Chrome and, while there's differences and Pros and Cons I notice to each, I'm not really bothered by anything except the fact that my audio player at the top is properly styled in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

It seems to me that the "height" CSS didn't take in Chrome for some reason, meanwhile it takes just fine in Firefox.

Any idea how to fix this issue? If not, at least help me to make it so that it'll display normally in Chrome, even if it *has* to be fat instead of the slim bar I wanted. At the very least I want it to be functioning and not obscured by the page, even if it's not exactly what I had envisioned.

I've tried several @media "hacks" to target only Chrome / webkit but they don't take either.

Profile in question located [here](http://oz.chatango.com) (flash required). Sources are freely available in the sources tab. The CSS classname is `.BGM`.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Images of the difference: https://imgur.com/a/EQyqD

You can see the problem - I want it to display correctly like it is in Firefox, not be crushed like it is in Chrome. I'd actually like to be able to style it further for Chrome - make it styled the same in Chrome as it is in Firefox - though I'm guessing that Chrome may just not be as flexible about this as Firefox is.

PS: Yes, insane that a site still runs on Flash over HTTP in 2018, and yes the profile designs on the site are all juvenile and edgy. It's a guilty pleasure of mine - and it's a nice little coding playground.

Comment: What height are you expecting? It's 18 for me on both browsers.

Comment: Changing the height to 30 seems to work nicely for Chrome, try it on your end.

Comment: In terms of trying to customise the look, you can always look at some of the external audio players: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag. Apparently it's not possible. with the native <audio>

Comment: In fact, changing the height to 30 on Firefox seems to have no detrimental effects, from what I can see.

Comment: My issue with that is that I want the audio player to be slim. But I suppose I'll have to make a compromise with Chrome. How would I go about targeting only Chrome using a modern method? Most threads I dig-up about the topic suggest the "@media hacks" I mentioned and are rather old, and the methods don't seem to work anymore. I do want to keep things with the player rather minimalistic if possible, not resorting to loads of styling to get it done, but I'll do what I must I suppose.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the height attribute within the `.bgm` class to something bigger, like 30.

If you're really attached to how the player looks on Firefox, you can also introduce some Chrome only margin to `.bgm`:

`-webkit-margin-before: 12px;`

If you want to make the Chrome player slimmer you will need to look into webkit masks, which requires an additional image file.

Comment: @Ozpin If you're using Flash, I don't think you ought to have high standards in terms of code filth xD Keep in mind that Flash is deprecated, and initially blocked by Chrome and Firefox. Chrome is even considering dropping support for it entirely. http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/07/25/chrome-will-completely-remove-flash-support-end-2020/