# html audio tag color inverted on chrome

Tags: css, html, audio

I am using HTML audio tag using the code,

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Which shows fine on firefox, but in chrome which inverted the color,

In Firefox,

[image]

But in Chrome,

[image]

The color inverted, How do I set the color like firefox?

Comment: Each browser implements it's own audio player. The design will vary by vendor.

Comment: @Turnip How to add custom design to audio tag?

Comment: Look at the duplicate question. [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)