# HTML5 Audio styling

Tags: html, css, sass, html5-audio

I want to style HTML5 Audio like this

[image]

```
 <audio controls>
  <source src="@Model.Audio.Mp3.Url" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

The above code creates the following audio

[image: Audio]

Has someone done similar styling or is it possible to do this styling in HTML5 audio player

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: @BookOfZeus Code is added thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not in a cross browser solution as they are built natively. There are a lot of `-webkit-` based psuedo elements that you can target for styling but those only work on webkit based browsers (eg: This won't work on Firefox/IE/Edge). However, you can utilize the audio API and there is a good answer on this [duplicate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126871/1527700) about using the JW Player which is a wrapper around this API and gives you styling control.

Comment: Someone that has duplicate capability may want to close this out as dupe to the linked SO question. Thanks.