# How to style the audio panel in HTML5

Tags: css, html, encoding

I would like to style the audio panel to show the play button only and not the volume control and time. The code I'm using is this:

```
<audio class="play_button" controls="" preload="none" style="width:175px" class="kskin" data-durationhint="1.55" data-startoffset="0"> <source src="audio/giraalaizquierda.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs=&quot;vorbis&quot;" data-title="Original Ogg file (100 kbps)" data-shorttitle="Ogg source" data-width="0" data-height="0" data-bandwidth="100377"></audio>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXknO.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the native controls.

You can only omit the `controls` attribute, then build your own UI (e.g. using a `<button>`) which controls the audio element with JavaScript.

Comment: I wrote this `<div class="play"> <button   onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"> <audio preload="none" style="width:175px" class="kskin" data-durationhint="1.55" data-startoffset="0"> <source src="audio/giraalaizquierda.mp3" type="audio/ogg; codecs=&quot;vorbis&quot;" data-title="Original Ogg file (100 kbps)" data-shorttitle="Ogg source" data-width="0" data-height="0" data-bandwidth="100377"></audio></button></div>` Can you show me the javascript part?