# How to remove rounded corners of an audio tag on Chrome and mobile device?

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I'm using the simple `<audio>` tag to play some audio files on my website

I see it as a rectangled shape when i open my website with chrome on my PC

but i see it with rounded corners if i open my website with chrome on my mobile

i want it as a rectangle shape with black color not white, it is already black on firefox but on chrome it is white and have rounded corners, i tried many different solutions without any results.

I will upload an image to clarify more

[image: my image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Comment: Would like to share html and css code?

Answer (score 3):

the css below will do the trick

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<audio controls src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-15s.mp3"></audio>
```

I was working on a custom audio player for a web app and faced the same issue, I looked at the chromium source code and found a solution that worked for me, even though the question is old but still i would like to share a solution for any one facing the same issue in the future

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping, i partially solved the problem by changing ( media-controls-panel ) background color into grey, then i changed the `<audio>` tag background color into the same color also ( i see it now as a rectangle because they have the same background color )

Unfortunately, i can't turn the ( media-controls-panel ) background color into black, first:- because the buttons are also black and they are really ugly,

second:- because i see a rounded grey shadow around the ( media-controls-panel ) even if i changed the audio background into black also.

This is my code

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel{
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,1);
width:350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
<audio preload="none" style="background-color:#C8C8C8;" controls 
    <source src="audio/audiofile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     Your Browser Does Not Support Radio</audio>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem still havn't found a good solution for this