# how to customize the pause button in the audio tag?

Tags: css

[image]

I want to put svg instead of the black button. how do you do it with css?

Comment: Short anwser you cannot, browsers will use their own controls, what you could do is create your own and use JS to play the audio and create the progress bar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Comment: @JayPatel no no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTMLMediaElement API to create your own [audio player with HTML/CSS](https://www.brainbeast.best/customizable-audio-player-for-webpages/). It is likely the only option. Because the default player can't be styled.