# Audio tag minimal play button

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a minimalistic play button, via the  tag of html5.
I've managed to strip down the play button to a bare minimum and I would like to remove the right part after the three dots, but I do not know how to do it. I'd like to strip the play button of the part indicated by the red arrow. I'm fine with the three dots that allow you to change the speed, I just need the part at the right of the dots to be minimal/disappear.

[image]

```css
audio {
  width: 110px;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
  display: none !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container {
  display: none !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
  display: none !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
Text before the play button
<audio oncontextmenu="return false;" controls controlslist="nodownload" name="media">  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Did you check this link?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element has a hard time getting to the max-width it needs, which is `84px` (because the two desired buttons are `32px` each and there is `10px` of padding on left/right side of audio element), most likely because buttons are loaded and then some are hidden. You can get around the width issue with an `animation` on load. Make it fast enough that end-user wouldn't notice, like `0.1s` - example below

```css
audio {
  width: 110px;
  animation: audioWidth 0.1s forwards;
}

auto::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  justify-content: center;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
  display: none !important;
  min-width: 0;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container {
  display: none !important;
  min-width: 0;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
  display: none !important;
  min-width: 0;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none !important;
  min-width: 0;
}

@keyframes audioWidth {
  from {
    width: 110px;
  }
  to {
    width: 84px;
  }
}
```

```html
Text before the play button
<audio oncontextmenu="return false;" controls controlslist="nodownload" name="media">  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved simply by changing the values of a few control panel settings. `audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel`

And slightly reduce the width of the `audio` tag.

```css
audio {
  width: 100px;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider, 
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container, 
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,  
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  padding: 0 0 0 1px;
  justify-content: center; /*control panel elements are flex positioned*/
}
```

```html
Text before the play button
<audio oncontextmenu="return false;" controls controlslist="nodownload" name="media">  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```