# Customize audio player to bring content from default html audio player?

Tags: html, css, audio

I'm creating a website on Cargo, which has its own Audio player (i'm attaching the code in the CSS editor at the end).
The thing is, Cargo only allows for 100mb media storage. As per their website, if I want to upload more media, I'd need to use a FTP server! Dropbox or similar won't work. I've been trying to figure out a solution to this for the last few hours with not much success

However, I know I can use the built in html5 audio player to play an audio file store in, for example, Google Drive. This works for me, however, I've been trying to style the audio player with not much success either. I've looked at the solutions at this thread [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)
However, I've not been able to properly change the background color to transparent, borders and play button to black, and have straight edges, which is what I would like...

I'm wondering, is there a way to use the Cargo player and still get source the file from Google Drive? I'm not a programmer but I'm comfortable editing  the CSS editor in Cargo, as that is what I use to create the website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers from Spain

`````
 * Audio Player
 */

.audio-player {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 3.3rem;
    outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-family: "Eurostile", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif, "Sans Serif", Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 1px 1px 1em 1px;
}

body.mobile .audio-player {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.audio-player .separator {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.audio-player .button {
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

.audio-player .icon {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    padding: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.audio-player .buffer {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.audio-player .progress {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.audio-player .progress-indicator {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: ew-resize;
}

.audio-player .note-icon {
    height: 100%;
    width: 3.8rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.audio-player .current-time {
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.audio-player .total-time {
    padding-right: 1rem;
}````
`````

Comment: Description for the _tag_ `cargo` you added to your question is _"Cargo is a thin wrapper that allows you to manipulate Java EE containers in a standard way. It is often used to start containers for integration and functional tests, especially with Maven or Ant."_ - I doubt that has anything to do with what you are talking about here ...?

Comment: You're right, @Cbroe. I've removed the tag.