Can't style standard audio tag
I'm not very strong in the front. I tried for 2 hours to remove the volume control, to remove at least something from the standard styling, but all in vain.
    {% for audio in audios %}
    <div class="col-7 audio-player" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <span><b>{{ audio.audio.author }}</b> {{ audio.audio.title }}</span>
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <audio controls="false" class="audio-element" data-audio-id="{{ audio.audio.id }}">
            <source src="{{ audio.audio.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
        {% comment %} <button class="btn btn-outline-primary play-audio" data-audio-id="{{ audio.audio.id }}">Play</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary pause-audio" data-audio-id="{{ audio.audio.id }}">Pause</button> {% endcomment %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger delete-audio"
        data-audio-id="{{ audio.audio.id }}">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}


.audio-player {
    width: 500px; /* Ширина плеера */
  }


    .audio-player audio {
     width: 100%;
     height: 40px;
     background-color: black;
  }

js if it need:
var audioElements = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

var successMessage = $("#jq-notification");

audioElements.forEach(audio => {
    audio.addEventListener('play', () => {
        audioElements.forEach(element => {
            if (element !== audio) {
                element.pause();
                element.currentTime = 0;
            }
        });
    });
});
audioElements.forEach((audio, index) => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        const nextAudio = audioElements[index + 1];
        if (nextAudio) {
            nextAudio.play();
        }
    });
});


const volumeSlider = document.querySelector('.volume-slider');

volumeSlider.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const volume = parseFloat(volumeSlider.value);
    audioElements.forEach(audio => {
        audio.volume = volume;
    });
});

the best that was possible was to hide the entire element completely, but I needed some parts, a volume control for example, I was looking for answers, but I only found some super strange and complex approach in which there is no audio at all, and where there is, they have everything perfectly stylized, but for some reason I don’t have it
Help me please(

simply remove the controls attribute -  as documented - you want only some controls, you'll have to create your own I think

Here are some pointers to style the audio element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag

But as Jaromanda X already pointed out: certainly in the long run, it is way easier to create your own user interface.
