# html 5 audio tag width

Tags: html, layout, html5-audio

I was wondering if it's possible to set the width of the audio tag. It is not a supported feature by default, so "hacks" will be happily accepted.
I already tried putting them in small div's and tables, but that doesn't look very smooth... As far as I can see, I'm the only one bothering about it, but I really appreciate some help

There is no need for cross-platform/browser support; I'm happy as long as FireFox (3.6 ++) supports it.

Quick example as to what I'll be using:

```
<audio preload="auto" id="id12" controls="controls" onended="func12();" src="http://192.168.1.68/mymusic.wav"></audio>
```

Comment: You can also consider `zoom: 70%;`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Set it the same way you'd set the width of any other HTML element, with CSS:

```
audio { width: 200px; }
```

Note that `audio` is an inline element by default in Firefox, so you might also want to set it to `display: block`.  [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/YK72D/).

Comment: Shame the Chrome player only expands to a width of 800px before centering itself.

Answer (score 23):

For those looking for an inline example, here is one:

```
<audio controls style="width: 200px;">
   <source src="http://somewhere.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It doesn't seem to respect a "height" setting, at least not awesomely.  But you can always "customize" the controls but creating your own controls (instead of using the built-in ones) or using somebody's widget that similarly creates its own :)

Answer (score 2):

You also can set the width of a audio tag by JavaScript:

```
audio = document.getElementById('audio-id');
audio.style.width = '200px';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use html and be a boss with simple things :

`<embed src="music.mp3" width="3000" height="200" controls>`