# What is the default width of a audio tag in html?

Tags: html

I need to know what is the default width of an audio player in HTML, I didn't see answers on google so any answers are accepted here. thanks.

Comment: Probably browser-dependent, no? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635365/html-5-audio-tag-width

Comment: This seems like it would be browser dependent. Better to just use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height