# box-shadow not being set for parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div defined like following:

```
<div id="purple" class="play">
        <audio id="purpleBoxAudioSorting" src="sounds/SortingPagePurpleBox.mp3"></audio>
        <p id="purpleBox">
            Content of the box
        </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to add box shadow on hover to div #purple, but it is set for the text inside of it(#purpleBox) rather than the parent div instead.

here is the CSS:

```
#purple {
    background: url('../images/purple box.png')  no-repeat center center; 
    position:absolute;
    left:344px;
    top:85px;
}


#purple :hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #FFF61D;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between `#purple` and `:hover`. Right now, your CSS is trying to add a `box-shadow` to any element you hover over within the element `#purple`.

Comment: How can I have the box-shadow only for the parent and not elements inside of it?Thanks

Comment: @user3739622 Implementing my change will do this for you. It will add the box-shadow to the div that has the ID of #purple, and it should not add a box-shadow to any elements within that div.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style audio players using CSS ([Custom CSS for <audio> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794682/custom-css-for-audio-tag)), so it's just shadowing what it can, which is the purpleBox div.

Comment: He isn't trying to style the audio player. He is trying to style the surrounding div.