# The appearance of HTML tag <audio> in different browsers

Tags: javascript, css, html, browser, html5-audio

I have an  tag in my HTML5/JSF page, as below:

```
<audio controls="x"> 
            <source src="resources/audio/test.wav" type="audio/wav" /> 
</audio>
```

When viewed from Firefox and Chrome browser, the appearance of the audio control is black-gray (audio2.png). And the appearance of the audio control is lighter (colorful) when viewed in Eclipse's "system default Web browser" (audio1.png).

I like the color of audio1.png better. Is there a way to achieve the appearance of audio1.png in Firefox and Chrome?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to do it. You [can't actually style the audio tag itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794682/custom-css-for-audio-tag), you can only create your own custom controls that look the same in all browsers.

As stated in the other answer, probably the best solution is to [use an existing player](http://www.jplayer.org/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and I will explore that. Actually I don't have to use a full audio player. What I really want is a little button on the page, when I click the button, it plays the audio. Is there a way I can change my HTML5 to achieve this?

Comment: If that's all you need, you should be able to do it using just JavaScript: `new Audio('path_to_file.mp3').play();`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) for more info and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) to get a better idea on what other things you could do using this API.

Comment: Can I also use .wav instead of mp3 file in Audio constructor?

Comment: You could, but [that wouldn't work on IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=wav). MP3 seems to still be the only one that works on all major browsers.