# How do i make an toggle button for audio only using html or css?

Tags: html, css, button, audio

i'm trying to make an toggle button for audio, where if you click on the button the audio turns off and click again it turns back on.

I have tried searching it up but have only found ways using javascript or jquery and i would prefer not using these.

```
<audio> <source src="../music/TheMUSIC.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/></audio>
```

This is the code i have for my music so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<audio controls> <source src="../music/TheMUSIC.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/></audio>
```

and add some custom css to it.

Comment: what do i use css on if i were to do so?
like what do i write before {}?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794682/custom-css-for-audio-tag) might help