# Using the default HTML5 <audio> player with a dark background leaves a semi-circle artifact, trying to figure out how to get rid of it

Tags: html, audio, border, default, artifact

So I've messed with most of the webkit stuff and can't figure what causing it. 0px border 0px padding, on and on. Anyone else run into this and figure out how to get rid of the artifact?

I posted an example of the problem I am having here:

https://mercenaryheart.com/audio%20artifact.html

Thought for a second that it might be my monitor, but I have three and it's on all of them.

Any one else run into this? Any suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>audio artifact</title>
    
</head>
    
    <style>
    
    body {background-color: #494949;}
        
        audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel{
    background-color: #494949;
}   

        audio {
    margin: 0px 512px 0px 0px;
            
}
        
    </style>

<body>
                
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    
        <div align="right"><audio controls><source src="
            
            decent girl snip.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to change it's style https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794682/custom-css-for-audio-tag

Comment: @ Najmieh Sadat Safarabadi Yes, I looked at that page. All the options I see relate to the controls. It has to do with the border or the container somehow. Creating new controls wont make the semi-circle go away. Tried that, didn't work

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: @ Rob removed the align, didn't help.